# Gradle + Eclipse: How to not export JARs that are dependencies of a dependency?

Tags: eclipse, gradle, build, gradle-eclipse

In my `build.gradle` file I have the following:

```
...
dependencies {
  ...
  testCompile (group: 'org.uncommons', name: 'reportng', version: '1.1.2') { exclude group: 'org.testng', module: 'testng' }
  ...
}
...
```

`reportng` needs `velocity-1.4.jar` and `velocity-dep-1.4.jar`, and actually the above `testCompile` dependency causes these 2 JARs to be fetched and to be placed into the Eclipse's `.classpath` file, as "exported" (that is, their checkboxes in the "Order and Export" tab of Eclipse's "Java Build Path" dialog are checked).

The fact that these 2 JARs get set as exported is a problem. I need them to still be fetched but not to be exported.

From the [Gradle doc](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.EclipseClasspath.html) I understand that this is done by using `noExportConfigurations` as per their example:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

configurations {
  provided
  someBoringConfig
}

eclipse {

  classpath {

    //if you don't want some classpath entries 'exported' in Eclipse
    noExportConfigurations += configurations.provided
  }
}
```

My problem is that I don't have a `configurations {}` section, and while I can certainly add one, I don't know what to put in it in order to exclude from export not the whole `reportng` but just two of the JARs that come with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably want something like:

```
configurations {
    noExport
}
dependencies {
    // replace with correct values
    noExport "foo:velocity:1.4" 
    noExport "foo:velocity-dep:1.4"
}
eclipse {
    classpath {
        noExportConfigurations += configurations.noExport
    }
}
```

PS: Please don't double-post here and on http://forums.gradle.org.

Comment: I had absolutely no idea that posting the same question here and on Gradle forum was bad. I sincerely apologize. Thanks for the answer, I will try it soon.

Comment: This is being follwed up [on Gradle forum](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/gradle_eclipse_how_to_not_export_jars_that_are_dependencies_of_a_dependency)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, in the year and a half that has gone by since [Peter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22029315/552792), noExportConfigurations is deprecated and slated to be removed in Gradle 3.0. What's more, none of the solutions in [the linked Gradle forum thread](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/gradle_eclipse_how_to_not_export_jars_that_are_dependencies_of_a_dependency) allow me to remove a dependency imported from a folder, like war/WEB-INF/lib, for instance.

So after much research, I stumbled upon an example here at the end of this [build.gradle file in GitHub](https://github.com/syfsyf/war-runner/blob/master/build.gradle), which reorders entries in the classpath:

```
withXml { xml ->
    def node = xml.asNode()
    node.remove( node.find { it.@path == 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.web.container' } )
    node.appendNode( 'classpathentry', [ kind: 'con', path: 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.web.container', exported: 'true'])
}
```

I modified the example so that it simply removes a JAR file using the regex capabilities of the Groovy Node. Note that the `xml ->` part is not needed, and that this entry is a child of the file closure:

```
withXml {
    def node = it.asNode()
    node.remove( node.find { it.@path ==~ /.*velocity-1\.4\.jar/ } )
    node.remove( node.find { it.@path ==~ /.*velocity-dep-1\.4\.jar/ } )
}
```